# how to go to another activity after successful login to Facebook in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

I have integrated Facebook in my Android App using Sessions. I have a Login Activity that has a button for Facebook login. I want to go to another activity called MainActivity after successful login to successful login in Facebook the app closes without any error or without going to the MainActivity. Can anyone suggest me where I should give the code to start the activity. Here is my code.

```
 ImageButton buttonLoginLogout,bb;
Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        buttonLoginLogout = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onClickLogin();

            }
        });


        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();


            }
        });


          Intent ik=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(ik);

        } }


    private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }



    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

             updateView();


        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: in onPostExecute you can start your main activity...

Comment: Do you know the code flow? just debug it, and you'll know where to put your code for starting another activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm){
                        //Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
                        Bitmap b1=bm;
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                        b1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  
                        // Log.w("bit",""+drawable);
                         String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

                         Editor edit=pref.edit();
                         edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
                         edit.commit();

                          Intent ik=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                          startActivity(ik);

                    }
                 };
                 t.execute();
```

Just move your

```
 Intent ik=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                              startActivity(ik);
```

this code inside postexecute method.

Comment: can u pls suggest something?

Comment: okay just use this code `Intent ik=new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                              startActivity(ik);` inside `updateView()` method.